# Using JavaScript, how can I create an array with a specific width (number of columns)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I have an array of columns that represents a row of data in a grid.

It looks something like the following:

```
let row = [rowId,'string value', 'string value 2', 'string value 3'];
```

I need to generate a dynamic row of data depending upon a variable number of columns the row will have.  In other words, I need the array to be initialized so it contains the id and then X number of columns (depending upon the variable number of columns the grid will have).

`[id, 'col-1', 'col-2', ...]`

I currently have a ridiculous method which works and looks like the following:

```
getNewRow(maxKey: number, rowWidth: number){
    switch (rowWidth){
      case 1:{
        return [maxKey, 'col 1'];
        break;  
      }
      case 2:{
        return [maxKey, 'column 1', 'col 2'];
        break;  
      }
      case 3:{
        return [maxKey, 'column 1', 'col 2', 'col 3'];
        break;  
      }
      case 4:{
        return [maxKey, 'column 1', 'col 2', 'col 3', 'col 4'];
        break;  
      }
      case 5:{
        return [maxKey, 'column 1', 'col 2', 'col 3', 'col 4', 'col 5'];
        break;  
      }
      case 6:{
        return [maxKey, 'column 1', 'col 2', 'col 3', 'col 4', 'col 5', 'col 6'];
        break;  
      }
      case 7:{
        return [maxKey, 'column 1', 'col 2', 'col 3', 'col 4', 'col 5', 'col 6', 'col 7'];
        break;  
      }
      case 8:{
        return [maxKey, 'column 1', 'col 2', 'col 3', 'col 4', 'col 5', 'col 6', 'col 7', 'col 8'];
        break;  
      }
      case 9:{
        return [maxKey, 'column 1', 'col 2', 'col 3', 'col 4', 'col 5', 'col 6', 'col 7', 'col 8', 'col 9'];
        break;  
      }
      case 10:{
        return [maxKey, 'column 1', 'col 2', 'col 3', 'col 4', 'col 5', 'col 6', 'col 7', 'col 8', 'col 9', 'col 10'];
        break;  
      }
    }
```

`maxKey` is just a simple way of insuring that the id column gets set to a new unique value.

**My Questions**

- Is it possible to generate a row of data like this dynamically?
- Is there some way to create a an array on the fly that has a dynamic width (based on the number of columns)?

Comment: Is the discrepency between `'col 1'` and `'column 1'` deliberate or a typo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an array of all the `col`s with their changing index string with `Array.from`, and then yu can spread that into the returned array.

```
const getNewRow = (maxKey: number, rowWidth: number) => [
  maxKey,
  ...Array.from(
    { length: rowWidth },
    (_, i) => 'col ' + (i + 1)
  )
];
```